# How can I capture the 'Cancel' on the deep linking system popup iOS 9?

Tags: ios, facebook, popup, ios9

When using the deep linking feature in iOS 9, the first new system popup is displayed that says '{your app} would like to open Facebook' there is also a popup that accompanies the call back 'Facebook would like to open {your app}'

I have whitelisted the FB URL's so that if user pushes 'OK' everything works fine... However, in order to improve my apps workflow, I need to be able to handle if the user presses 'Cancel' on the initial popup.

How can I capture if user presses 'Cancel' on the new iOS 9 deep linking system popup(s)?

I am building using Xcode 6.4 and Facebook SDK 4.5

Comment: Please update to the Facebook iOS SDK 4.6, which determines the best experience for your user. In most cases this will mean the SafariViewController, which includes the cancel button from FB, and you can use that to know if people cancelled login.